# How to create electronically signed PDF in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

Can any one have any idea about how to create a electronically signed pdf using ColdFusion.

Your timely help is well appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The facility to do this was added to *CF11* (https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfpdf#cfpdf-Digitallysigningthedocuments). It's not present in earlier versions. You might have to use a third-party library rather than a native CFML solution, I think.

Comment: Can you help me by pointing out any better third party library so that I can use.

Comment: No, I have no idea: I've never had to do it. I was simply RTFMing for you. I'm sure someone else will though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472370/how-to-implement-digital-signature

Answer (score 1):

ColdFusion 11 Enterprise has the capability to digitally sign your current pdf's designed in liveCycle.

iText also can support liveCycle forms and sign them, but it appears a bit tricky.

From what I understand you need to convert your liveCycle form in order to have iText get at it.